# What is the regular expression to use with match to look for delimiters but actually exclude them in the result in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

The question might be more confusing than what I am trying to do. Basically I want to get the content of the html `<title` element:

```
s = s.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
```

This gives me:

```
["<title>foobar</title>", "foobar"]
```

So to access the text only, I have to use `s[1]`.

Is there any way to create a match with just the text, skipping `"<title>foobar</title>"`? Or with other words: is there a way to tell `match()`: "search for a string delimited with `<a></a>` but ignore those delimiters in the result"?

I have tried various expressions with negative lookbehinds and such, but I wasnt lucky. I dont even know if that is the correct approach.

Comment: There's been load of such questions. Read documentation. JS does not support lookbehinds, only lookaheads. Use `RegExp.exec` and get the captured texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I've looked on SO already. Do you have a similar question?

Comment: If the `s[1]` part really bothers you that much, you can do `s = s.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/)[1];` (but only if you're sure that there will always be a match.)

Comment: Actually, I can also add: *parsing HTML with regex is not recommended*. :)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know that its evil, but I have no choice :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so the answer is, its not possible to exclude those matches from the result?

Comment: @Alex: Right, I already mentioned that in my first comment in a *JS does not support lookbehinds*.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but not clearly :) thanks anyways

Comment: Please clarify why you *"have no choice"* but to use a regex to parse html?  Is it a business decision (your client has, for some reason, specified that you must use a specific technology to solve their business problem)?  "I have no choice" sounds fishy.   Many (most?) issues are that are considered "no choice" are actually an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  For example you could simply parse the html into jquery and use `$("title").text()`

Comment: @freedomn-m i would love to, but the comment characters limit is too low to fully explain. I am fully aware of how evil html parsing with regex is and for the most part I dont even do, just for some `<head>` related parts. To give some hints why I have to some parsing: ajax, history.js, Drupal

Comment: None of which explain why you can't parse what you want rather than use a regex.  If there's a good reason, then fine, but at least 10% of questions on SO are XY problems because someone (in the chain) came up with a solution to a problem and then tried to get answers to problems with that solution rather than answers to the *actual* problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m thats true, but I dont apply to that XY problem in this case :) thanks a lot for your input!

Comment: @freedomn-m http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149397/should-i-use-an-iframe-rather-than-using-ajax maybe you have a hint or two